# Sound not Playing on Contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a simple game in which a ball jumps over obstacles. When it comes in contact with an obstacle (either upon jumping or when it collides before jumping), i want to play a sound before transitioning to the main menu screen (GameScene.Swift). There will definitely be a detection of didBeginContact but not necessarily didEndContact
For some reason the sound file does not play. What am i doing wrong?

PlayScene.Swift file

```
class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
    //......
    let losingSoundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("losing.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    //....

   func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      //play the losing sound
      self.runAction(losingSoundAction)

      contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue
      died()
   }

   func died(){
      //change back to main screen
      if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
         let skView = self.view as SKView!
         scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
         scene.GameSceneInstance = self
         scene.score = score
         skView.presentScene(scene)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: does didBeginContact execute? If not, have you set the class as the physics delegate?

Comment: yes didBeginCOntact executes because the scene changes to the main GameScene

Answer (score 0):

i moved the died() function call to didEndContact() and that seemed to solve the problem.